# using nao with ros hydro

Tags: ros, nao-robot, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a dialogue classifier that I have implemented in ros and I want to test it on the NAO robot. Is it possible to use the simulation of the NAO provided by rviz? does rviz allow me to subscribe to the nodes of the simulated robot to access data being publihsed by other nodes in my package? I am using ros hydro on ubuntu 12.04.4.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126571/using-nao-with-ros-hydro/) by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2014-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Be careful: `rviz` is *not* a simulator. It only *displays* what the real robot or the Nao's simulator (webots) publishes.

So what you likely want to do (if you can not work directly on the real robot) is to install "Webots for Nao" (download it [from this page](https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/resources/) -- requires an Aldebaran account) and then follow the [installation instruction for ROS + Nao](http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Installation/remote).

---

Originally posted by [severin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2119/severin/) with karma: 240 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-02-06**:
I have the robot in my lab with the intels atom as the processor. If I want to use the robot, then should I still use ROS on my laptop or put ROS on the robot itself. I dont know which direction to choose in the tutorials...I am getting confused with the options..please help..thanks

**Comment by [severin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2119/severin/) on 2014-02-06**:
If you want to work on the real robot, install [ROS on Nao](http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Installation/local) AND on your computer (to communicate with the robot). But if you have only limited experience with ROS and ROS deployment on robots, you should maybe first start with the simulator only.

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-02-06**:
THe tutorial sates that it is for ros groovy where as I already have ROS-hydro on my computer.Does the tutorial work for ros hydro as well? Apart from the tutorial u provided in the above comment, do I also need to follow the other cross compiling tutorials like http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling_Catkin ?

**Comment by [dnth](https://answers.ros.org/users/11961/dnth/) on 2014-02-22**:
you can choose to weather run ROS remotely or run ROS on Nao itself (cross compiling). For me i did not choose to cross compile but to run ros remotely. And it also works

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-02-22**:
yes that is what i did eventually. I thought i needed to cross compile when i was running ermotely on my latop but it was actually the other way. I am now running ROS remotely on my laptop and using rviz to test my code.